# Xcode warning symbols - yellow triangle with a white CIRCLE?

Tags: ios, xcode

So I'm used to seeing the red circle with the exclamation point and the yellow triangle with the exclamation point... but what does the yellow triangle with the circle mean?

[image]

Comment: This simply means that the compiler has a suggestion for how to fix what it found as an issue. This shows up frequently if you are trying to print something with NSLog and you use the wrong `%` escape character sequence, and things like that. It will suggest a fix, and even apply the fix for you

Answer (score 7):

It has a suggestion how to fix the warning, double click the triangle and it gives you options.  Click those option/s and it will fix the warning for you